# Runtime of Arrays.copyOfRange()

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

What is the big-O runtime of Java's Arrays.copyOfRange(array, startIndex, endIndex) function?

For example, would it be equivalent or less efficient in terms of both space and time complexity to write a simple binary search on arrays function using copyOfRange rather than passing in the start and end indices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Arrays.copyRangeOf()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.copyOfRange%28long%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29) uses [`System.arraycopy()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.arraycopy%28java.lang.Object%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cint%2Cint%29) which uses native code (could use [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) for example - depending on JIT implementation) under the hood.

The "magic" behind copying with `System.arraycopy()` is making one call to copy a block of memory instead of making `n` distinct calls.

That means using `Arrays.copyOfRange()` will be more efficient than any other solution you'll choose to implement by yourself.

Further, I don't see how a binary search could help here: an array has direct access - and here we know precisely the src, dst and how many items should we copy.

From the big-O perspective, the complexity will be `O(n*k)` where `n` is the number of items to copy and `k` is the size (in bits) of each item. Space complexity is the same.

Comment: It's more efficient for copying things, yes, but not for the specific use case the OP mentioned, which need not involve any copying.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.copyOfRange` takes linear time -- with a low constant factor, but still linear time.  Manipulating the start and end indices will inevitably be asymptotically faster, O(log n) instead of O(n).